# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type flash.geom:Matrix

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, bitmap, tile

Im confused, I passed a matrix datatype into the this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(); and i get Implicit coercion of a value of type. below is my code.

```
var theMatrix:Matrix;
            theMatrix = new Matrix();
            this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tileImage,theMatrix.translate(30,0));
            this.graphics.endFill();
```

and the followig error sprigs

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type flash.geom:Matrix.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal you are passing to the `beginBitmapFill` function a parameter `theMatrix.translate(30,0)` who return nothing (`void`)

do this instead:

```
theMatrix.translate(30,0);
this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tileImage,theMatrix);
```